# Count file contents correctly when names have spaces or other characters

Tags: awk

Have the following input file

```
Wiraqucha (Ancient Guardian)
Ebonscreech
Brassdarter the Surpreme
Stonelash the Gilded
Warknife
Azuredarter
Auriccall
Ragshell the Subjugator
Slenderguard
DeathSurge
Regalspool
Vaultwatch
Whitestride the Ever-Thirsty
```

Need output to list each entry and the number of times it occurs like this

```
Wiraqucha (Ancient Guardian) (1)
Ebonscreech                  (1)
Brassdarter the Surpreme     (1)
Stonelash the Gilded         (1)
Warknife                     (1)
Azuredarter                  (1)
Auriccall                    (1)
Ragshell the Subjugator      (1)
Slenderguard                 (1)
DeathSurge                   (1)
Regalspool                   (1)
Vaultwatch                   (1)
Whitestride the Ever-Thirsty (1)
```

Following code works, however it splits at every space which is not what I want

```
INPUT="RBList.txt"
RBNLog="RBNames.txt"
while IFS=""
read linename
  do echo "Rare bosses appearing in Harbour bridge story zone: $linename" >> "$RBNLog"
     echo $linename
done < $INPUT
#
#
#
HBRRBCurrList=$(grep -e 'Rare bosses' "$RBNLog" | awk '
{
  sub(/.*story zone: +/,"")
  if(!NF){ POERBInfo["Anon"]++ } 
  for(j=1;j<=NF;j++){
    POERBInfo[$j]++
  }
}
END {
  for(RB in POERBInfo) {
      print RB,"("POERBInfo[RB]")"
  }
}'|sort)


RBNameList="RBNStats.txt"
LogStartDate="September 14th 2020"
echo -e "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------" >> "$RBNameList"
echo -e "Rare Bosses in HB Story zone (not including Vaal side area) to date: $HBRRBCurrList \n" >> "$RBNameList"
echo -e "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------" >> "$RBNameList"
```

How do I get the second piece Of code to provide the desired output (and not split each name along space or brackets/hyphens) ?

Comment: It would really help if your sample data included a name that was included more than 1 time. And, we don't really need 15 of the same type of data to understand the problem. 3-5 lines sample data should be enough. It seems that you're using a ListOfNames and then reading the same file to count the references. Usually, we use a ListOfNames(file) to match against a one or more *different* files to count against. Would that work for your use case?

Comment: I'm not looking to match against files, just names in a file. The first file is read and send names, along with a count of each name to a second file. I'm looking to count how many times a name appears in the second file. The code is already there but I need it to read the names properly and not split them at each space in a name. Your suggestion isn't what I'm looking for I'm afraid

Comment: OK. Figured it out. Added -F"  {2,}" at the beginning of the awk statement. Now it captures each line correctly (though formatting is off a little)

Answer (score 1):

```
HBRRBCurrList=$(grep -e 'Rare bosses' "$RBNLog" | awk -F" {2,}"'
{
  sub(/.*story zone: +/,"")
  if(!NF){ POERBInfo["Anon"]++ } 
  for(j=1;j<=NF;j++){
    POERBInfo[$j]++
  }
}
END {
  for(RB in POERBInfo) {
      print RB,"("POERBInfo[RB]")"
  }
}'|sort)
```

Comment: 1) Glad you found a solution to your problem. 2) Yes, when I said *"we use a ListOfNames(file) to match against a one or more different files to count against."*, I should have said *"we use a ListOfNames(file) to match against **the text in** one or more different files to count against.*  I didn't mean match filenames. 3) I'm not sure I understand `-F" {2,}"`, so I'll upvote your Q if you break that down/explain it in the body of your Answer. 4) Finally, you can accept your answer after 48 hrs (I think), and gain valuable reputation points. CrazyAwk indeed! ;-) Keep posting!

Comment: You never need grep when you're using awk and what you're doing doesn't make sense with respect to the sample input/output in your question - you're trying to separate input by 2 or more spaces and relying on that not existing in your input so you can count 1 line at a time as if it were a field at a time and looping from 1 to NF hoping that NF will only be 1, etc...

Comment: Hey Shellter - the command -F" {2,}" means I'm strictly defining FS as being 2 or more space characters. This means it will treat each of the lines as a whole, not 3 separate entries. I'm sure there are more eloquent methods to do so. If I entered all the data on a single line for example I would not be able to use this method. It only works as long as each entry is on it's own line. As the farmer says to the pig in the movie Babe "That'll do ..." and yes I can mark my answer as accepted in another 24hrs. Thanks for the input and comments everyone !

Comment: Ed - you're right in that it's not necessary to use grep with awk most of the time. The more I get used to awk the more I'll improve how I structure things in the future

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be your problem:

```
  for(j=1;j<=NF;j++){
    POERBInfo[$j]++
  }
```

You might just want this, since you've already removed the part before the colon:

```
  POERBInfo[$0]++
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sort file | uniq -c
  1 Auriccall
  1 Azuredarter
  1 Brassdarter the Surpreme
  1 DeathSurge
  1 Ebonscreech
  1 Ragshell the Subjugator
  1 Regalspool
  1 Slenderguard
  1 Stonelash the Gilded
  1 Vaultwatch
  1 Warknife
  1 Whitestride the Ever-Thirsty
  1 Wiraqucha (Ancient Guardian)
```

If that's not all you need then edit your question to provide more truly representative sample input/output.